# Changing Plot Point Color to Reflect Data

Tags: r

How would I fix my plot so that say lower GDP is more black and higher GDP is more red? (I'm in an introduction Data Lit & Vis class, fairly new to R)

```
data <-read.csv("rosling.csv") 
head(data)

tail(data)

median(data$pcGDP)
median(data$life.expectancy)

#median per-capita GDP: 4500.592
#median life expectancy: 72.84712

options(scipen=999)
data$gdp <- data$pcGDP*data$total.population
data$gdp[data$country=="United States"]
#calculated GDP of the United States: 14419400000770

data$gdp[data$country=="Niger"]
#calculated GDP of Niger: 5410608052

data$gdp[data$country=="Bahrain"]
#calculated GDP of Bahrain: 25713571418

mean(data$pcGDP)
# 12825

#Part 3
plot(log(data$pcGDP),
     data$life.expectancy, 
     cex=(data$total.population/1000000000)+1, 
     col=if(data$pcGPD <= 12825){
       "red"
     } else{
       "black"
     }
)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: For such use of color it might be an example to switch to 'ggplot2'.  If you stay with base graphics, make a function like codegrey  <-  function(var,min,max) {
  var  <- (var-min)/(max-min)  
  var  <-  round(100*var)
  col1  <-  paste("grey",var,sep="")
  col1}
      and use it for the col= argument to plot. Example use: codegrey(runif(10),0,1)  which gives result    codegrey(runif(10),0,1)
 [1] "grey52" "grey58" "grey99" "grey31" "grey67" "grey48" "grey44" "grey4" 
 [9] "grey3"  "grey63"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `rgb` function. It takes values for red, green and blue and outputs a colour. Black corresponds to zero for red, green and blue. So to go from black to red, you can just set green and blue to zero and increase the red value.

You need values between zero and one, so first you should convert your variable to this range

```
# make a copy of the data$pcGDP variable
x <- data$pcGDP

# convert to [0,1]
x <- (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))

# create a vector of colours
col <- rgb(x, 0, 0) 

# plot
plot(log(data$pcGDP),
     data$life.expectancy, 
     cex=(data$total.population/1000000000)+1, 
     col=col
)
```

Obviously I can't do it on your data, but it worked fine when I tested it on artificial data.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (which only gives greyscales) (A better solution would be to switch to `ggplot2`  graphics system) is given below.  Make the function

```
codegrey  <-  function(var,min,max) {
  var  <- (var-min)/(max-min)  
  var  <-  round(100*var)
  col1  <-  paste("grey",var,sep="")
  col1}
```

An example call with generated output is below:

```
codegrey(runif(10),0,1)
 [1] "grey52" "grey58" "grey99" "grey31" "grey67" "grey48" "grey44" "grey4" 
 [9] "grey3"  "grey63"
```

And then you can use it in a plot command like this:

```
plot(log(data$pcGDP),
     data$life.expectancy, 
     cex=(data$total.population/1000000000)+1, 
     col=codegrey(log(data$pcGDP),min(log(data$pcGDP)),
                                   max(log(data$pcGDP)))
)
```

(but you should'nt call your data frame "data", you wouldn't call your dog "dog"! )  To get a list of all the color names known to R, type the command 
`colors()`.